# How to reference a generic class with a constraint from a Protocol with a typealias in Swift?

Tags: swift, protocols, generics

I'm try to define a protocol `P2` so that it returns a generic class with a constraint on another protocol `P1`, e.g:

```
protocol P1 {}

class C<T : P1> {}

public protocol P2 {
    typealias T
    class func c() -> C<T>
}
```

But this results in the following compiler error:

```
error: type 'T' does not conform to protocol 'P1'
    class func c() -> C<T>
```

There doesn't seem to be any combination that allows this, e.g. the next obvious syntax:

```
protocol P1 {}

class C<T : P1> {}

public protocol P2 {
    typealias T
    class func c() -> C<T : P1>
}
```

Errors with:

```
error: expected '>' to complete generic argument list
    class func c() -> C<T : P1>
                          ^
note: to match this opening '<'
    class func c() -> C<T : P1>
```

Is this possible to do in Swift?

Comment: Have you tried imposing the constraint on the `typealias`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have never used constraints like that, but I think you can just define it in the typealias - I've tried it in a playground and compilation succeeds:

```
typealias T: P1
```

Comment: AMAZING! Been running into Swift generics limitation for two days, and finally reached a hurdle which has a solution. [Thought I'd share my use case](https://gist.github.com/Mazyod/fc640f2348db3b622097). I had to remove the details, but the feature is essential for protocol oriented programming.